# Calculating interest rates in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question that is not a repeat. I am looking for a built in numpy function (though it could also be a part of another library) which, given an original loan amount, monthly payment amount, and number of payments, can calculate the interest rate. I see numpy has the following function:

```
np.pmt(Interest_Rate/Payments_Year, Years*Payments_Year, Principal)
```

This is close to what I am looking for but would instead prefer a function which would provide the interest rate when given the three parameters I listed above. Thank you.

Comment: What is the formula you want to implement ? Interest rate calculation has finesses. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`numpy.rate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html#numpy.rate) from [numpy_financial](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/).

An example usage: suppose I'm making 10 monthly payments of $200 to pay off an initial loan of $1500. Then the monthly interest rate is approximately 5.6%:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> monthly_payment = 200.0
>>> number_of_payments = 10
>>> initial_loan_amount = 1500.0
>>> np.rate(number_of_payments, -monthly_payment, initial_loan_amount, 0.0)
0.056044636451588969
```

Note the sign convention here: the payment is negative (it's money leaving my account), while the initial loan amount is positive.

You should also take a look at the `when` parameter: depending on whether interest is accrued after each payment or before, you'll want to select the value of `when` accordingly. The above example models the situation where the first round of interest is added *before* the first payment is made (`when='end'`). If instead the payment is made at the beginning of each month, and interest accrued at the end of the month (`when='begin'`), the effective interest rate ends up higher, a touch over 7%.

```
>>> np.rate(number_of_payments, -monthly_payment, initial_loan_amount, 0.0, when='begin')
0.070550580696092852
```